# Call XPages Dialog in typeAhead

Tags: dialog, xpages

is it possible to call a Dialog component in typeAhead functionality?
What i want to do is If the user enter a word which does not come up with  typeAhead function then a dialog should appear on the screen.
Please find my code below (my dialog is in custom control)

Regards 
Cumhur Ata

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
<xe:dialog id="dialogConfirmation">
 <div class="modal-body">
                <p>You have entered a word which is not in the list</p>
                <p class="text-warning">Please add/or cancel<small> </small></p>
            </div>
    <xe:dialogButtonBar id="dialogButtonBar1">
        <xp:button value="Hayır" id="btnConfirmYes">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.closeDialog('#{id:dialogConfirmation}')]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
        <xp:button value="Evet" id="btnConfirmNo" styleClass="btn-primary">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="complete">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:openNewFrm(sessionScope.extDbPath,sessionScope.expDbPage)}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
    </xe:dialogButtonBar>
     <xe:this.title><![CDATA[#{javascript:var c = "Warning";return c;}]]></xe:this.title></xe:dialog></xp:view>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hijack the result of the typeahead and call your dialog if it's empty by using this snippet:

https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=typeahead-onstartoncomplete-event

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Domino Designer at hand right now so I can't try this out. So this is just guessing:

I don't think that you can use the standard Edit Box control's type ahead feature for something like that; instead you could program this yourself using the control's "onkeyup" event, mimicking the standard type ahead. the idea is that a classic type-ahead operates as a filter to a list of possible entries, just like a "getElementsByKey" method that is fired upon each key stroke. So with every event you check what's in the Edit Box so far, compare it to your list, then display the filtered result to the user in a pop-up (you may want to use a dojo tooltip here).

If the result is null you can bring up your dialog instead.